# Windows shell: get parameter value from file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `C:\parameters.txt` that contains different parameters, for example:

```
env_user=username123
env_pw=password123
env_url=example.com
```

Now I created a `.cmd` file that needs to get these values and put them in a variable, for example:

```
SET var_user=<Here I need 'username123'>
SET var_pw=<Here I need 'password123'>
SET var_url=<Here I need 'example.com'>
```

How do I write this in my cmd script to get the correct values for my variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution thanks to different inputs.

```
@echo off  
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (C:\parameters.txt) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="env_user" set var_user=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="env_pw" set var_pw=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="env_url" set var_url=%%B
    )
```

This will set the correct variables (not local) once the specific code name (before the `=` in `parameters.txt`) has been found.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a delimiter for `=` character so that words before/after `=` will be separated. Besides that, you need an array to `set` each of the parameters. You can do it like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set increment=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (C:\parameters.txt) do (
    set parameters_array[!increment!]=%%b
    set /a increment+=1
)
echo %parameters_array[0]%
echo %parameters_array[1]%
echo %parameters_array[2]%
pause >nul
```

Keep in mind, array always starts from 0. You could change to `set increment=1` if you prefer the array starts from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight alternative to dark fang's solution, since your `parameters.txt` file's contents are already in the format of `variable=value`, you could

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("c:\parameters.txt") do set "%%I"

rem // display env_* variables
set env_
pause
```

The `usebackq` option allows you to quote the file name, which might be needed if you ever move `c:\parameters.txt` to a location containing spaces, ampersands, or other tricksy characters.  It's a good habit to follow when reading the contents of text files with `for /f`.

Also, it's better not to use delayed expansion if you don't need it, as delayed expansion can sometimes corrupt values containing exclamation marks -- a situation that is reasonably possible when dealing with passwords.